# Getting force close when device is locked,rotate and ulocked again

Tags: android

I am developing a tablet app. Everything is working fine until device is locked. Once the device is locked and rotated, then the force close appears.

I forced my app to run on **LANDSCAPE** mode only. So I mentioned this permission in the menifest.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**So when I am locking my device and its rotated then the orientation changed and this force close generated.**

To resolve this, I added this permission in the menifest.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

And in the code:

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.i("Log", "Configuration changes called");
        int orientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        // or = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        setRequestedOrientation(orientation);
    }
```

I have also added this line in the **onCreate()**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("Log", "OnCreate");
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.lyt_login_main);
                ........
                }
```

***But still its not getting resolved. Please help me out to solve this issue.***

**This is the error I am getting:**

```
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marico.icp/com.marico.icp.activity.LoginActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03000f
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:128)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1165)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03000f
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1037)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2144)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:870)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at com.marico.icp.activity.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:77)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
12-17 11:13:57.877: E/AndroidRuntime(10462):    ... 12 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats because you dont have the appropriate resource in Landscape mode

Comment: u mean to say layout, right??

Comment: I have created layout-large-land folder and kept the layout there. Its working very fine until the device is locked.By locking and unlocking also its working fine. BUT BY LOCKING,ROTATING THE DEVICE AND UNLOCKING IT GIVES AN ERROR

Comment: Put your layout in res/layout not in layout-land. android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"  Comment this method onConfigurationChanged, comment this line too setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); build a fresh and run the code.

Comment: @kumar .Its working fine, but now I am facing one issue. when its orientation changes after locking the screen then after unlocking its again calling the onCreate() and previously entered data lost.

Comment: thanks kumar, ur solution helped me. I added your solution with some update in my answer

Comment: @kumar your suggestion is already voted by me mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kumar said in comment,

I kept all the layout in the layout folder from layout-large-land, changed the menifest permission from 
`android:configChanges="orientation"` to `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`

Commented this method `onConfigurationChanged()`, commented this line too `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

And then I run the code.
this solved the issue of the force close, **but due to orientation change, the onCreate() method called and and I was loosing the entered data into the editText,**

So for this I **override** the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method to my activity class. And did following.

I was saving the entered data in the **hashmap,** so in the `onSavedInstanceState()`, i did this.

```
@Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putSerializable("hashMap", hashMapSaveToDB);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }
```

And in the `onCreate()` checked for the savedInstanceState like this...

```
if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            hashMapSaveToDB = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("hashMap"); 
        }
```

This solved the loosing of the data at the time of **onCreate()** called.

Thanks to @kumar

Answer (score 0):

remove this line 
android:configChanges="orientation"

what is happening is when the orientation is changed it tries to relaunch the activity and it goes to oncreate after every oreintation change.

comment this method 
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

```
}
```

it is of no use

Comment: i tried this. but its still calling the oncreate method while unlocking

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the activity of manifest--

```
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```